# How to increase radio button size in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do increase the default size of my radio buttons given by bootstrap?
 Here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/thomassuckow/a815d1yz/

```
html
    <form >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">Test 1 - Bootstrap</div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <input type="radio" id="q156" name="quality[25]" value="1" checked="checked" /> Normal
                    </label> 
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" id="q157" name="quality[25]" value="2" /> History
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have used the required bootsrap js, css and fonts.

Comment: Makes button pixelig in Firefox

Answer (score 30):

You can increase height and width.

```
input[type=radio] {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Or you can use `transform scale`

```
input[type=radio]{
  transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

```css
label:first-child input[type=radio] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

label:last-child input[type=radio] {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">Test 1 - Bootstrap</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
          <input type="radio" id="q156" name="quality[25]" value="1" checked="checked" /> Normal
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" id="q157" name="quality[25]" value="2" />History
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1up for the transform. If I used the fixed 30px to enlargen the radio inputs, the margins get messed up. Bootstrap is somehow happy if I use the transform instead.

Answer (score 5):

Add css `radio button #id` in `transform:scale(..)`

```
input#q156 {
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

```css
input#q156 {
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">Test 1 - Bootstrap</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
          <input type="radio" id="q156" name="quality[25]" value="1" checked="checked" /> Normal
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" id="q157" name="quality[25]" value="2" />History
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: scale makes the button pixelated in safari

Comment: This is work on a higher version of safari: http://prntscr.com/p3rm29 @AlbuquerqueWebDesign

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 5 and if you're using SASS 
Alter these variables

```
// Size of Radio
$form-check-input-width: 1.5em;

// Height between
$form-check-min-height: 2.5em;
```